# bower install modernizr... where is modernizr.js?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

I want to install modernizr so:

```
bower install modernizr
```

and everything seems OK, but when I check inside bower_components/modernizr I cannot see anywhere (not even sub-directories) a modernizr.js or any file that has the content of modernizr.js for that matter...

On a similar note if I install jQuery

```
bower install jquery
```

bower "says" that it has installed jQuery 2.1.1 but I cannot find it anywhere. The 'dist' directory has only jquery.min.map

If instead I require jQuery latest 1.X

```
bower install jquery#^1
```

I get in dist jquery.js etc.

Why I went through all this? Because originally I wanted to install yeoman webapp

```
yo webapp
```

And proceeded to choose everything (sass, bootstrap and modernizr). But when I went to run it

```
grunt serve
```

I got this:

```
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
app/index.html modified.

modernizr was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "C:\mobapps_html5\Working\bower_components\modernizr" f
or the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task
app/styles/main.scss modified.

modernizr was not injected in your file.
Please go take a look in "C:\mobapps_html5\Working\bower_components\modernizr" f
or the file you need, then manually include it in your file.

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "copy:styles" (copy) task


Done, without errors.

Running "sass:server" (sass) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.
File .tmp/styles/main.css.map created.

Done, without errors.

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/styles/main.css created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://localhost:9000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Modernizr was not injected (of course it is not there!!!) and jQuery does not work (the link in index.html points to nothing... jquery.js is not there, same as per modernizr)

Comment: @goodMan seriously? "This is driving me crazy" edited out? OK. Anyway I found the answer... I will post it for posterity.lol, this is driving me nuts would have been better? nevermind.

Comment: generally editorialized comments like emotion are edited out since they don't help anyone and cloud the actual issue.

Comment: @DreadedMonkey , editing is a good deed. It is not a punishment. Everyone can encounter the same problem after a while and it's better to have clean questions and answers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution - **clean the cache**:

```
bower cache clean
```

and magically everything is OK.

Comment: I have the same issue and cleaned the cache as suggested but it doesn't answer the question: where is the modernizr.js file that I need to include?  there should be a `dist/` or something but there isn't.  did you figure that out?

Comment: Try doing `cd <path to your bower_components>/modernizr && npm install` and then running `grunt build` (see [Saint48198's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40076667/520661) below).

Answer (score 4):

When you get modernizr from bower, you will need to go to the directory where you download modernizr and run npm install. Once that is done, run grunt test and grunt will create a dist in modernizr folder folder with a modernizr-build.js file in it.

Comment: `grunt build` generates the same file and runs much quicker than the test suite.

Comment: Not sure why, but `grunt build` did not generate the `modernizr.js` file. `grunt test` did.